# Not sure how to organize content in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@anushkas/57c8f6) I have a bar chart application with filters. I have included a side menu in the app. I need for the bar chart to display on the main screen and filters to display in the side menu. Currently, my bar chart is overlayering the side menu, like this-
[image] [image]

I am not sure how to organize content on the main screen or the side menu. Maybe I am using the wrong package? The filters interact with the bar graph, that's why they can't be written out in different functions.

If viewing the snack, Clicking anywhere on the screen opens the side menu.

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, TextInput, Picker, Button } from 'react-native'
import MenuDrawer from 'react-native-side-drawer'
import {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react'
import {Chart,LineChart,BarChart,PieChart,ProgressChart,ContributionGraph} from 'react-native-chart-kit'

const initialData = [12, 19, 12, 25, 22, 10];
const initialFrom = "0"
const initialToMonth = "7"
const months = [
      { month: "Jan", value: "0" },
      { month: "Feb", value: "1" },
      { month: "Mar", value: "2" },
      { month: "April", value: "3" },
      { month: "May", value: "4" },
      { month: "June", value: "5" },
    ];
const initialLevelsArr = [
          "Jan",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "April",
          "May",
          "June",
        ];
const initialLabels = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June"];

export default function App() {

   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)


   const toggleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(!open)
  };

  /*const toggleClose = () => {
   setOpen(false)
 };*/
 const [filterLimit, setfilterLimit] = useState(100);
 const [lessThanOrGreaterThan, setlessThanOrGreaterThan] = useState("greaterThan");
 const [datas, setDatas] = useState(initialData);
 const [from, setFrom] = useState(initialFrom);
 const [toMonth, setToMonth] = useState(initialToMonth);
 const [labels, setLabels] = useState(initialLabels);

   const applyFilter = () => {
     const isLessThan = lessThanOrGreaterThan === "greaterThan";
     const value = filterLimit;
     // update instance variable
     const newDatas = initialData.map(v => {
     if (isLessThan ? v >= value : v <= value) return v;
         return 0;
     });

     setDatas(newDatas);
   }

   const applyDateFilter = () => {
       const newLabels = initialLevelsArr.slice(
         parseInt(from),
         parseInt(toMonth) + 1
       );
       const newDatas = initialData.slice(
         parseInt(from),
         parseInt(toMonth) + 1
       );

       setLabels(newLabels);
       setDatas(newDatas);
     }

 const dataset = {
     labels: labels,
     datasets: [
       {
         data: datas,
         colors: [
           (opacity = 1) => `red`,
           (opacity = 1) => `blue`,
           (opacity = 1) => `yellow`,
           (opacity = 1) => `green`,
           (opacity = 1) => `purple`,
           (opacity = 1) => `orange`
         ]
       }
     ]
   }

  const drawerContent = () => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.chartContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleOpen} style={styles.animatedBox}>
        <Text>Close</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
            numeric
            placeholder="Filter Limit"
            value={filterLimit}
            onChangeText={text => setfilterLimit(text)}
          />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
      <Picker
        selectedValue={lessThanOrGreaterThan}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setlessThanOrGreaterThan(itemValue)}
      >
        <Picker.Item label ="Greater Than" value="greaterThan" />
        <Picker.Item label="Less Than" value="lessThan" />
      </Picker>
    </View>
     <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => applyFilter()}
        title = "Apply Filter"
        color="#841584"
    />
    </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MenuDrawer
          open={open}
          drawerContent={drawerContent()}
          drawerPercentage={45}
          animationTime={250}
          overlay={true}
          opacity={0.4}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleOpen} style={styles.body}>
            <Text>Open</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </MenuDrawer>
        <BarChart
              data={dataset}
              width={300}
              height={220}
              withCustomBarColorFromData={true}
              flatColor={true}
              fromZero={true}
              chartConfig={{
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                backgroundGradientFrom: '#ffffff',
                backgroundGradientTo: '#ffffff',
                data: dataset.datasets,
                color: (opacity = 1) => '#fff',
                labelColor: () => '#6a6a6a',
              }}
            />
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  chartContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
    },
    pickerContainer: {
     paddingHorizontal: 24,
     marginLeft: 100
   },
    inputContainer: {
    marginTop: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  filterContainer: {
  marginTop: 100,
  paddingHorizontal: 24,
},
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 30,
    zIndex: 0
  },
  animatedBox: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#38C8EC",
    padding: 10
  },
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F04812'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed some ui to fit the screen hope this is how you wanted

snack:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  Picker,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import MenuDrawer from 'react-native-side-drawer';
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  Chart,
  LineChart,
  BarChart,
  PieChart,
  ProgressChart,
  ContributionGraph,
} from 'react-native-chart-kit';

const initialData = [12, 19, 12, 25, 22, 10];
const initialFrom = '0';
const initialToMonth = '7';
const months = [
  { month: 'Jan', value: '0' },
  { month: 'Feb', value: '1' },
  { month: 'Mar', value: '2' },
  { month: 'April', value: '3' },
  { month: 'May', value: '4' },
  { month: 'June', value: '5' },
];
const initialLevelsArr = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April', 'May', 'June'];
const initialLabels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April', 'May', 'June'];

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  /*const toggleClose = () => {
   setOpen(false)
 };*/
  const [filterLimit, setfilterLimit] = useState(100);
  const [lessThanOrGreaterThan, setlessThanOrGreaterThan] = useState(
    'greaterThan'
  );
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState(initialData);
  const [from, setFrom] = useState(initialFrom);
  const [toMonth, setToMonth] = useState(initialToMonth);
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState(initialLabels);

  const applyFilter = () => {
    const isLessThan = lessThanOrGreaterThan === 'greaterThan';
    const value = filterLimit;
    // update instance variable
    const newDatas = initialData.map((v) => {
      if (isLessThan ? v >= value : v <= value) return v;
      return 0;
    });

    setDatas(newDatas);
  };

  const applyDateFilter = () => {
    const newLabels = initialLevelsArr.slice(
      parseInt(from),
      parseInt(toMonth) + 1
    );
    const newDatas = initialData.slice(parseInt(from), parseInt(toMonth) + 1);

    setLabels(newLabels);
    setDatas(newDatas);
  };

  const dataset = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: datas,
        colors: [
          (opacity = 1) => `red`,
          (opacity = 1) => `blue`,
          (opacity = 1) => `yellow`,
          (opacity = 1) => `green`,
          (opacity = 1) => `purple`,
          (opacity = 1) => `orange`,
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  const drawerContent = () => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.chartContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleOpen} style={styles.animatedBox}>
          <Text>Close</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
            numeric
            placeholder="Filter Limit"
            value={filterLimit}
            onChangeText={(text) => setfilterLimit(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
          <Picker
            selectedValue={lessThanOrGreaterThan}
            style={{ height: 50, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              setlessThanOrGreaterThan(itemValue)
            }>
            <Picker.Item label="Greater Than" value="greaterThan" />
            <Picker.Item label="Less Than" value="lessThan" />
          </Picker>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={() => applyFilter()}
            title="Apply Filter"
            color="#841584"
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MenuDrawer
        open={open}
        drawerContent={drawerContent()}
        drawerPercentage={45}
        animationTime={250}
        overlay={true}
        opacity={0.4}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleOpen} style={styles.body}>
          <Text>Open</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <BarChart
          data={dataset}
          width={300}
          height={220}
          withCustomBarColorFromData={true}
          flatColor={true}
          fromZero={true}
          chartConfig={{
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            backgroundGradientFrom: '#ffffff',
            backgroundGradientTo: '#ffffff',
            data: dataset.datasets,
            color: (opacity = 1) => '#fff',
            labelColor: () => '#6a6a6a',
          }}
        />
      </MenuDrawer>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  chartContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    zIndex: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  pickerContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    marginTop: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  filterContainer: {
    marginTop: 100,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 30,
    zIndex: 0,
  },
  animatedBox: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#38C8EC',
    padding: 10,
  },
  body: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F04812',
  },
});
```